# Install latest package version in Kaggle

Tags: pandas, pip, kaggle

I am using Kaggle ([www.kaggle.com](http://www.kaggle.com)) and trying to install pandas 1.5 (the latest version today).

By default, the version of pandas in the environment is 1.3.5

I tried to :

```py
%pip install --upgrade pandas
```

and

```py
%pip install --upgrade pip
%pip install --upgrade pandas
```

and also

```py
%pip install --upgrade pip
%pip uninstall pandas --yes
%pip install pandas==1.5
```

All these methods lead to a pandas 1.3.5 being reinstalled.

I also tried to clone and install pandas from source (unsuccessfully).

Before running these commands, I set the notebook's settings to "internet on", and "always use the latest environment".

[image]

How do I install pandas 1.5 today? And why does my previous commands are not working?

Answer (score 0):

You actually did reinstall pandas. In order for the change to take effect, you need to restart the kernel. Run -> Restart & clear cell output

Comment: The issue was not to install a new package. The issue was that Kaggle is probably running a local Pypi, which made it impossible to fetch the latest version of a package on Kaggle ( pip install pandas was installing pandas 1.3.5 while 1.5 was available on pypi).